# How to prevent react rerender when generating a file?

Tags: reactjs, rerender

I'm making a request to an API that creates a PDF file on my public folder. After getting response react automatically re-renders the page and ignores everything else to do.

I need to redirect to another page with the name of the generated PDF but re-renders the same page.

```
API.post('some_url', formData) //this creates a pdf file on public folder
        .then(res => {
          //Ignores redirection
          this.props.history('other_page', res.pdf_name)
        })
```

I found that the problem was creating the pdf file by trial and error, and when pasting manually a file in the public folder it automatically re-renders the page where i'm currently.

How can i prevent this behavior?

Comment: Are you using some kind of dev server that automatically re-renders on file changes. ?? if so you need to skip watch the folder you are creating the pdf

Answer (score 1):

As suggested by [Panther](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61692062/how-to-prevent-react-rerender-when-generating-a-file#comment109123415_61692062) it was my dev server. I used create-react-app for the project, so looking up on how to disable hotreload i stumble onto [this answer](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/2519#issuecomment-318867289) and it worked.

Thanks for the heads up.